# Can I replace the headphone jack on an iPhone SE?

Tags: headphones, repair, iphone

I have the tip of a headphone jack stuck in the headphone socket in a brand new iPhone SE.

I went to Apple looking for a repair and they said that it wasn't repairable and that I'd have to spend £200 (~$290) on a replacement.

I have found instructions on how to replace an iPhone 5s headphone jack [here](http://m.imore.com/how-replace-broken-headphone-jack-iphone-5s?_ga=1.177487653.1695391203.1464125222#slide2). Does anyone know if I will be able to follow the same instructions for the 5s using a SE? Also, will I be able to use the same part as it's the same form factor?

Comment: I can say that apple products are notorious for their difficult repairs. Are you sure you cannot pull out the remains of the headphone plug. Was it really a headphone plug that got stuck in the headphone jack? Please send an image.

Comment: The last time my headphone jack broke in the socket was when it got ripped out during a flight - I managed to get it out with a pair of pliers, some elbow grease and patience. Of course, this depends on whether you have anything to grab on to, in my case part of the rod that connected the layers together was sticking out. Otherwise, I would think that the form of the jack for both SE and 5S should be the same unless Apple made some under-the-hood improvements. It's probably best to check with iFixit's teardowns and see if the architecture around the jack seems the same.

Comment: iFixit did a comprehensive [teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/iPhone+SE+Teardown/60902) of the iPhone SE. Many components seem to be interchangeable but the assembly containing the headphone jack doesn't seem to be one of them (step 10). It also looks like a very tricky repair, I'd work on attempting to extract the stuck jack. Can you provide a photo?

Comment: Sometimes jewelry stores will use their small tools to reach in to the headphone jack and yank out the debris if you throw some cash their way. Worth a shot.

Comment: I've tried getting it out with strong glue on the end of a piece of dowel. Unfortunately, there is nothing to grip onto to pull it out.

Comment: Get a tiny drill bit and drill enough of it away that it falls out?

Comment: Looks like the part is [not compatible](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+SE+Lightning+Connector+Replacement/61312) with the 5S. Appreciate the suggestion @StephenCollins but I don't trust myself not to do unrepairable damage. Although if I'm going to replace it anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, it is possible to replace the Lightning connector assembly, which includes the headphone jack and microphone:

[image]

[Ifixt.com](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+SE+Lightning+Connector+Replacement/61312) has a guide on how to do this.  It's rated as a moderately difficult procedure; if this is not something you are experienced with, it's best to have a pro tackle this type of repair.